DuraDrive MV Synthetic transmission fluid in my 2015 Town & Country?
I’m looking to add automatic transmission fluid to my 2015 Chrysler Town & Country van. The manual says to only use “ATF +4 Automatic Transmission Fluid”.
The only fluid they have at my local gas station is “DuraDrive MV Synthetic”. I looked through the specs of this fluid online. The specs says it is suitable for “Chrysler ATF +3®#, MOPAR ASRC”. I’m not sure if that would work or not.
I suspect I need to get a fluid that specifically says “ATF+4” but figured I’d ask the experts on here. Thanks!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Chrysler (in its various incarnations) has released numerous Technical Service Bulletins since the early 2000's that emphasize and repeat that it is not OK to use ATF +3 in any vehicle that came from the factory with ATF +4.
Opinions vary, but you know what they say about opinions and the people who give them online.
If you care at all about doing right by your vehicle, you'll follow the manufacturer's guidelines. The last time I needed ATF +4, I ordered Valvoline online, and it was way less expensive than the ATF +4 stocked by the dealer. I see that it's now more widely available at auto parts stores and big box stores that carry auto supplies.

Thank you very much.
